# Полная отчистка таблиц от тестовых данных

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо полностью отчистить все таблицы от тестовых данных. Также надо сбросить все значения `Identity` колонок и подготовить БД к запуску новых тестов.

Как правильно делать `TRUNCATE` таблицы, стоит ли использоватьп параметр `DROP STORAGE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клазулу `DROP STORAGE` для [TRUNCATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html#GUID-B76E5846-75B5-4876-98EC-439E15E4D8A4) указывать не обязательно, та как она установлена по умолчанию:

> Specify DROP STORAGE to deallocate all space from the deleted rows from the table except the space allocated by the MINEXTENTS parameter of the table. [...]
>   This setting, which is the **default**, is useful for small and medium-sized objects.

`TRUNCATE` не сбрасывает `identity` колонку на начальное значение, это надо сделать отдельно:

```sql
alter table table1 modify (id generated as identity (start with 1));
```

Comment: Про сброс да в курсе спасибо. Про дефолтное понял

Comment: А почему вы  отказались от удаления схемы и создания её с нуля? Так обычно делают в тестовом окружении.

Comment: @0xdb, такой подход очень удобен в том случае если у разработчика нет прав для создания схемы и дачи прав/квот на дисковое пространство.

Comment: Удалить схему не получится, права ограничены

Comment: @quaresma89 А почему прав нет, это же тестовая БД, как я понял? И ещё просьба, раз вы не приняли ответ, то наверное у вас есть ещё пункты нуждающиеся в прояснении. Добавте их пожалуйста прямо в тело вопроса.

Comment: @0xdb, БД боевая и администрирую ее не я, выдали права только на развертывание необходимых таблиц,триггеров и так далее

Comment: @quaresma89 Тут не могу спорить. Просто решение подобной задачи с удалением схемы может понизить трудозатраты в десятки раз. Так как, все обычно пытаются экономить, то поэтому и спросил.